# Lucene Scoring Function - bias towards shorter documents

Tags: java, apache, lucene, tf-idf

I want Lucene Scoring function to have no bias based on the length of the document. This is really a follow up question to [Calculate the score only based on the documents have more occurance of term in lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758987/calculate-the-score-only-based-on-the-documents-have-more-occurance-of-term-in-l/12186362#12186362)

I was wondering how Field.setOmitNorms(true) works? I see that there are two factors that make short documents get a high score:

1. "boost" that shorter length posts - using doc.getBoost()
2. "lengthNorm" in the definition of norm(t,d)

[Here is the documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html)

I was wondering - if I wanted no bias towards shorter documents, is Field.setOmitNorms(true) enough?

Comment: Look into custom Similarity implementations (derive from DefaultSimilarity and override LengthNorm, Tf, Idf and other functions used for score calculations), it may help you to understand the process further.

Comment: We had the same effect and it worked well with Field.setOmitNorms(true) setting the similarity to    searcher.setSimilarity(new DefaultSimilarity() {
    @Override
    public float tf(float freq) {
     return 1;
    }
   }); this switched off counting terms and taking document length into account.

Answer (score 1):

Using BM25Similarity you could reduce to 0f:

> @param b Controls to what degree document length normalizes tf values

or

> @param k1 Controls non-linear term frequency normalization (saturation).

Both params will affect SimWeight

```
indexSearcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity(1.2f,0f));
```

More explanation can be found here : http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/

Answer (score 0):

Shorter docs are meant to be more relevant when you use TF-IDF scoring.

You can use your custom scoring functions in Lucene. Its easy to customize the scoring algorithm. Subclass DefaultSimilarity and override the method you want to customize.

There's a code sample [here](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/advanced-topics/scoring.html) that will help you implement it